# Hexadecimal string on a US Military challenge coin

Tags: cipher

I have been given a string which I believe to be in hexadecimal.

The string comes from the edge of a US Military challenge coin (non-sensitive information). A photo of the coin:

[image: Challenge Coin Hex]

> 746c417007684c24507154244d65527e4974416a006d4e24596b55760074496100744c6554610c24426d4e634f25

All I know is that it is a puzzle - I do not know the nature of the solution. (Literally only been told that "nobody gets it, but the solution is actually simple". Big grain of salt...)

I've tried various things like hex to ascii, UTF-8, etc.

Can someone help me solve?

Comment: Is this a _real_ challenge coin? A bit of googling doesn't turn up any sign that the JCOG has ever issued one (nor even very much sign that the JCOG even exists, though e.g. it is mentioned in a Wikipedia page) but maybe there's not much reason to expect such information to be online. What's up with the thick white rectangle on the front-of-coin image?

Comment: And can you tell us anything about where this puzzle comes from? E.g., were you approached by a JCOG member who has one of these coins? From the image I am guessing not that.

Comment: (To be clear, I am not in fact suggesting that JCOG isn't real; there's enough about it out there to make that unlikely. I mention the fact that it isn't super-visible on the internet as context for the more specific fact that I didn't find any sign of challenge coins issued by JCOG or on its behalf.)

Comment: Gareth, Fair questions. Yes, it is real. The thick rectangle contains the name and rank of the person this coin was minted for. I blanked it out for their privacy. They are a LT Cmdr in JCOG.  I learned a few things last night talking to them.  1. The riddle/puzzle/cipher was created by an Annapolis graduate. 2. The hex string encompasses the entire edge of the coin. What I mean is the string may not start/stop at the where I've shown.